I am trying to use rplidar with Ubuntu Noetic
I have two problems.
The first is when I write
ls -l /dev |grep ttyUSB

nothing happens.
The second is when I write
roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch**

it gives me this error
RLException: [view_rplidar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rplidar_ros] nor is [rplidar_ros] a launch file name 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file


Please don't change the question (drastically), such as removing a question  (i.e. the first ls query) that has already been answered because that makes existing answers not make much sense. You should probably revert the last edit. Also, questions should really only contain one query, although in this case it is a bit too late now, as query number 1 (that you've deleted) has been answered.

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I have rolled back your last edit and updated the error to the complete error from your comment under the answer

Problem 1.
try
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*

instead of
ls -l /dev | grep ttyUSB

or and * after ttyUSB
Problem 2.
are you in dir '~/catkin_ws'?
and make sure you did
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

before launch

problem 1 solved but problem 2 i did and still the same error                                   LException: [view_rplidar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rplidar_ros] nor is [rplidar_ros] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

@fatma - Your comment should be an update to the question, so that all of the information is both complete and all in one place, rather than spread across various posts and comments. Also, you say that you get the same error, but the error in the comment is not the same as that in your question. Is the error in your question partial or incomplete? If so, you should definitely update the question with the complete error, if you want to get an accurate answer. Finally, a code formatted error in the question would be easier to read than a unformatted error in the comments.
